# Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() causing a deadlock in a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have an application that makes heavy use of Async / Await. I'm running into a problem that I cannot explain.

I'm calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and I'm encountering a deadlock. I'm not understanding why given that I'm within a Windows Service which shouldn't have a `SynchronizationContext`. Furthermore, I grabbed a dump file from the process when it was hung-up, opened it in Visual Studio and the value of `System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current` was `null`.

Why is this blocking? I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: Why are you calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in *an application that makes heavy use of Async / Await*? You're missing the code that reproduces/context-explains this behaviour.

Comment: Show us the hot-spots (code-blocks) for you think there is a deadlock scenarios.

Comment: I suppose you are trying to call an `async` method in a `synchronized` approach. If yes then why not encapsulate the method call in an `Task.Run()` and get its result like:`Task.Run(async()=> await yourAsyncMethod()).Result.` .

Comment: Reduce your code to a minimum example that demonstrates the issue, and you'll probably find where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of async/await you should avoid using GetResult(), accessing the Result member of Task, or calling the Wait() method of Task. Doing so blocks the Thread, not only the Task, resulting in all Tasks on that Thread being blocked, and usually leading to deadlock.

Instead, you should await the Task. Using await does not block the thread, so it allows other Tasks to complete.